# mass deletion batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have been tasked with stripping out around 50 thousand .INI files from a windows folder that has 58 thousand files in it the issue is that the files aren't in order and removing these manually would be very time consuming.

The files themselves use number Id's as their naming convention and I managed to get an Excel spreadsheet together with all the ID's I need to remove. My question is, can I put these ID's somewhere like a batch file and get it to remove these if so how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the files to be deleted are the only `.ini` files then `del "c:\start folder\*.ini" /s`.

Comment: Or `for /f "delims=" %%A in (filelist.txt) do echo del %%A`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest script that will work:

```
cd "C:\directory\location\"
del "*.ini" /s
exit
```

The first line makes sure its in the directory that all the files are in, the second one deletes all the files in the specified folder and all of its subfolders (the subfolders can keep their .ini files if you remove the `/s`), and the third line quits the batch file. The third line is not necessary. The first line can be revoked if the batch file (`.bat`) is in the same folder as all of the .ini files.